# Regex to extract 1 letter followed by 7 numbers

Tags: regex

I am struggling with using RegEx to extract the following single letter followed by seven numbers `E3285270` from this URL:

```
http://photos.v3.torontomls.net/Live/photos/FULL/1/270/E3285270.jpg?20150812131646
```

Could someone please show me what regex string will grab it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use word boundaries. `\b` called word boundaries which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\d{7}\b
```

In js,

```
str.match(/\b\[a-z]\d{7}\b/i)[0]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eR0kE9/1)

Comment: Wouldn't `[a-zA-Z][0-9]{7}` be better? ... `\w\d{7}` seems undesired don't you think? https://regex101.com/r/rX9kJ2/1